# How to access the service on the server which act as the VPN Gateway as well?

Tags: networking, vpn, centos, routing, strongswan

I am currently running a VPN Gateway by Strongswan on a CentOS 6.5 VPS.

The CentOS server has one eth port.

The VPN is using IKEv2 and the connections between clients and server are established.
The clients are assigned virtual IPs drawn from a 10.0.0.0/24 pool. The clients can also access each other without a problem. However I notice that the server itself which acts as the VPN Gateway does not have a virtual IP address.

I am running some services on the VPS server which I would like to secure them by the VPN tunnel. If possible, I wouldn't expose them directly to the internet.

So I am wondering if there is a way for the connected VPN clients to access services on the server which acts as the VPN gateway through the tunnel? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does your config look like? In particular the `leftsubnet` setting on the server and the `rightsubnet` setting on the client. If you use `0.0.0.0/0` then the clients can access your server as usual because all traffic is tunneled.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use 0.0.0.0/0 for leftsubnet on the server. And I use the windows 7 VPN client in IKEv2 mode to connect. I also setup the internet request from the clients to be forwarded on the eth0 port on server so I can access the service listen on the server eth0 port as normal. To be more specific, what I would like to achieve is that, running some services behind the firewall, and they listen on some ports on local network, say like localhost. And only the connected VPN users could access them. Could you please give me some suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

If the clients route all the traffic to the server (i.e. with `leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0`) you only have to make sure the private services are only accessible via VPN. This is quite simple to achieve with strongSwan. Just accept IKE and IPsec traffic (and possibly SSH and other protocols you want to allow) on the `INPUT` chain and then set the default policy to `DROP`:

```
# allow ESP
iptables -A INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
# allow IKE
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
# allow NAT-T (IKE and ESP-in-UDP)
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
# allow SSH and other protocols
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
...
# drop packets by default
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Then configure `leftfirewall=yes` and `lefthostaccess=yes` in `ipsec.conf` so that strongSwan will automatically insert rules that allow your VPN clients to access the server. These rules use the IPsec policy matching module for iptables/Netfiler (`-m policy`) so they only apply to traffic coming from established IPsec tunnels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably I did't clarify my question clearly. This is exactly the same iptables setup as mine. The problem I met was how the virtual subnet for the clients can securely connect to the service on the server since the server itself is not presented in that subnet. For example, I try to run a apache facing the virtual subnet. I am wondering which ip address should the httpd process listen to? Thank you.

Comment: You won't need any special IP address for apache, just use the public IP (same as the VPN server) to access it from clients. Since you block traffic from all but the VPN clients no one else can access the service. Of course, you could use a different IP, but since the clients route everything to the VPN server it really doesn't matter which IP that is.